Will my USA B2 visa renewal be through a drop-box after a recent denial of a UK visa?
I have had a UK visa refusal 2 years ago. I filled the form incorrectly not disclosing about the savings in my bank account for the question "Do you have any other source of income or savings?".
I have to apply for a US B2 visa again. I have traveled twice to the USA and recently to Europe. Will it be a drop box without any bank statement being asked? And if bank statement is asked will I be questioned if I have a significant balance since I have good savings?
